# Route data angular in another component

Tags: angular, routes

I have some route like this

```
{
    path: 'new-url/:Id',
    component: NewUrlComponent,
    data: { heading: 'NewUrlComponent' }
}
```

And in **NewUrlComponent** i can get that data easy like this

```
 this.heading = this.route.snapshot.data.heading;
```

The problem I have is that I have another component on screen, somehow i need to display that **data heading** in that another component. I dont know is thats even possible?

Comment: If you inject `ActivatedRoute` in your other component, you can get the heading there too.

Comment: No i got undefined

Comment: Then you can use a `RxJS BehaviorSubject` to pass data between two components using a service.

Comment: Problem is that i two components does not use same service, i will needed to create new service just for that?

Comment: Yes, create a shared service and thus you can get the data in any of the components you want.

Comment: The problem is that i go out from tht route i need to set that heading to default

Comment: Maybe state management maybe help you to do that

Comment: Then you need to subscribe to the route `this.route.params.subscribe()`

Comment: Please write and answer if you know, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access the data heading from another component, but you can create a Service which will load(or subscribe to) this data, which you can access from any component.

```
Class NewUrlComponent {
  ngOnInit() { 
  this.service.headingData = this.route.data.heading;
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that i go out from that route i need to set that heading to default